# Using Pandas to calculate the difference between column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with two columns, Dates and Profits/Losses that I have read into the data frame.

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
cpath = os.path.join('..', 'Resources', 'budget_data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(cpath)
df["Profit/Losses"]= df["Profit/Losses"].astype(int)
```

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2019-01-01", 40],
        ["2019-02-01", -5],
        ["2019-03-01", 15],
    ],
    columns = ["Dates", "Profit/Losses"]
)
```

I want to know the differences of profits and losses per month (with each row being one month) and so thought to use df.diff to calculate the values

```
df.diff()
```

This results however in errors as I think it is trying to calculate the dates column as well and I'm not sure how to make it only calculate the profits and losses.

Comment: Can you post the data head pls

Comment: Please post a few lines of data, and full error messages so we can help.

Comment: Also if it's currently giving you an error it would help if you could share the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2019-01-01", 40],
        ["2019-02-01", -5],
        ["2019-03-01", 15],
    ],
    columns = ["Dates", "Profit/Losses"]
)

data.assign(Delta=lambda d: d["Profit/Losses"].diff().fillna(0))
```

Yields

```
    Dates      Profit/Losses   Delta
0   2019-01-01  40             0
1   2019-02-01  -5             -45.0
2   2019-03-01  15             20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,4]]

d = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['loss', 'profit'])

d.insert(0, "diff", [d['profit'][i] - d['loss'][i] for i in d.index])

d.head()
```

Gives:

[image: diff]